# Parent div larger than child by a small white border and I can't figure out why

Tags: html, css

I want the background to be rounded at the left hand side (i.e the red background curved and occupying the full left side of the parent div) and it isn't. I can't seem to figure out why this is the case.

```css
.body {
  background: #e7e7e7e7;
  font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
}

.course {
  /*only takes 
  /*padding adding to the existing container*/
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: #fff;
  position: absolute; /*this makes it stuck to the document body or the nearest ancestor which has a parent. When you scroll it's still all good. */
  width: 700px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(
    -50%,
    -50%
  ); /*this is RELATIVE to the actual elements size. We moved down from doc by 50%, so now need to move up by 50% to balance out. */
  /*ALT: width: 70%;
  left: 15%; */
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline-style: none;
}

h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0.6;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.preview {
  background: #e40046;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  outline-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Card UI design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap");
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* box-sizing: border-box; CAN ALSO EDIT SIZE LIKE THIS*/
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="course">
        <div class="preview">
          <h6>Course</h6>
          <h2>Web Development</h2>
          <a href="#">View All Chapters</a>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="progress-wrapper">
            <div class="progress">
              <span class="progress-text">8/9 Challenges</span>
              <h6>Chapter 4</h6>
            </div>
            <h2>JAVASCRIPT, HTML & CSS</h2>
            <p class="p-trunc">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis
              autem culpa architecto dolores quibusdam deleniti pariatur
              corporis, voluptatum ipsa explicabo.
            </p>
            <button class="btn">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error is with `div class` and `div preview`.

Comment: there is no need for the fiddle you can do a snippet here on the site. Also what exactly do you want? A rounded boarder on the left hand side of the red container?

Comment: .course { padding: 0; } will fix it

Comment: Thank you that solved it :) Never knew padding affects div size but after reading a bit more on it it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.body {
  background: #e7e7e7e7;
  font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
}

.course {
  /*only takes 
  /*padding adding to the existing container*/
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: #fff;
  position: absolute; /*this makes it stuck to the document body or the nearest ancestor which has a parent. When you scroll it's still all good. */
  width: 700px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(
    -50%,
    -50%
  ); /*this is RELATIVE to the actual elements size. We moved down from doc by 50%, so now need to move up by 50% to balance out. */
  /*ALT: width: 70%;
  left: 15%; */
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline-style: none;
}

h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0.6;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.preview {
  background: #e40046;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  outline-style: none;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Card UI design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap");
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* box-sizing: border-box; CAN ALSO EDIT SIZE LIKE THIS*/
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="course">
        <div class="preview">
          <h6>Course</h6>
          <h2>Web Development</h2>
          <a href="#">View All Chapters</a>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="progress-wrapper">
            <div class="progress">
              <span class="progress-text">8/9 Challenges</span>
              <h6>Chapter 4</h6>
            </div>
            <h2>JAVASCRIPT, HTML & CSS</h2>
            <p class="p-trunc">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis
              autem culpa architecto dolores quibusdam deleniti pariatur
              corporis, voluptatum ipsa explicabo.
            </p>
            <button class="btn">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```